# When fixing near-duplicates, how to group fuzzy-matched records in Postgres 9.6+

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, similarity

We have an application that has been erroneously inserting duplicates into the database. As a result I have been asked to identify the duplicates and group them together for review. There are roughly 500 thousand records, some are indeed unique, but most have at least one duplicate.

A duplicate in this case can mean rows that are either exactly, or close to be the same thing. For example, a person may have been added with the address `124 Main St` and then again with `124 Main St`, and yet again with `124 Main Street`. To find these dupes I've been using `similarity()` and that seems to work as desired.

I am having trouble figuring out how to get my query to group duplicates together.

Given a build schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
   id  BIGINT NOT NULL,
   first_name TEXT,
   last_name TEXT,
   street_address CHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Users (id, first_name, last_name, street_address) VALUES
  (7, 'JAMES','FAZ', '39392 Example Pl'),
  (1, 'JOE','FOO', '124 Example St. SE'),
  (223, 'MARK','BAZ', '566 Example Blvd'),
  (3, 'JOESEPH','FOO', '124 Example St. SE'),
  (5, 'JOE','FOO', '124 Example Street SE'),
  (55, 'CHARLES','BOO', '399 Example Lane'),
  (54, 'JOESEPH','FOO', '124 Example St. Southeast'),
  (4, 'KATIE','BAR', '1455 Example Ave'),
  (7, 'KATIE','BAR', '1455 Example Ave'),
  (866, 'JAMES','FAZ', '39392 Example Place'),
  (33, 'KATIE','BAR', '1455 Example Avenue')
;


CREATE TABLE Dupes (
   id  BIGINT NOT NULL,
   first_name TEXT,
   last_name TEXT,
   street_address CHAR(50),
   searched_name TEXT,
   searched_user_id bigint
);
```

Which generates a table like:

```
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| id  | first_name | last_name | street_address      |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 7   | James   | Faz    | 39392 Example Pl          |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 1   | Joe     | Foo    | 124 Example St. SE        |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 223 | Mark    | Baz    | 566 Example Blvd          |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 3   | Joeseph | Foo    | 124 Example St. SE        |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 5   | Joe     | Foo    | 124 Example Street SE     |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 55  | Charles | Boo    | 399 Example Ln            |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 54  | Joeseph | Foo    | 124 Example St. Southeast |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 4   | Katie   | Bar    | 1455 Example Ave          |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 7   | Katie   | Bar    | 1455 Example Ave          |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 866 | James   | Faz    | 39392 Example Place       |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 33  | Katie   | Bar    | 1455 Example Avenue       |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
```

I want the same data but 'ordered' to look something like this:

```
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| id  | first_name | last_name | street_address     |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 55  | Charles | Boo    | 399 Example Ln            |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 1   | Joe     | Foo    | 124 Example St. SE        |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 3   | Joeseph | Foo    | 124 Example St. SE        |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 54  | Joeseph | Foo    | 124 Example St. Southeast |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 5   | Joe     | Foo    | 124 Example Street SE     |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 4   | Katie   | Bar    | 1455 Example Ave          |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 7   | Katie   | Bar    | 1455 Example Ave          |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 33  | Katie   | Bar    | 1455 Example Avenue       |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 866 | James   | Faz    | 39392 Example Place       |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
| 7   | James   | Faz    | 39392 Example Pl          |
+-----+---------+--------+---------------------------+
```

My attempts have been akin to the following

```sql
WITH
Matching (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    l.id
    , l.first_name
    , l.last_name
    , l.street_address
    , r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name 
    , r.id
  FROM Users l
  JOIN Users r
  ON SIMILARITY(l.first_name || ' ' || l.last_name || ' ' || l.street_address,
                  r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name || ' ' || r.street_address) > .50
      /*AND CAST(l.id AS int) = 72918*/
)
-- SELECT * FROM Matching
INSERT INTO Dupes (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id)
  (
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id
    FROM Matching
  )
  ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;

SELECT * FROM Dupes;
```

This attempt results in a lot of repeated data.

---

The groups themselves can be in any order, it just matters that similarish records are grouped together in the final output.

Not sure if it helps but here's a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b501f7/1/0) with the above data in case it might help someone with tinkering around.

Answer (score 2):

This might do it:

```
WITH
Matching (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    l.id
    , l.first_name
    , l.last_name
    , l.street_address
    , r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name 
    , r.id
  FROM Users l
  JOIN Users r
  ON SIMILARITY(l.first_name || ' ' || l.last_name || ' ' || l.street_address,
                  r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name || ' ' || r.street_address) > .50
   and r.id>l.id
)
INSERT INTO Dupes (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id)
  (
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id
    FROM Matching order by id
  );

SELECT * FROM Dupes order by id;
```

Here is another possibility:

```
WITH
Matching (id, first_name, last_name, street_address, searched_name, searched_user_id) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    l.id
    , l.first_name
    , l.last_name
    , l.street_address
    , r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name 
    , r.id
  FROM Users l
  JOIN Users r
  ON SIMILARITY(l.first_name || ' ' || l.last_name || ' ' || l.street_address,
                  r.first_name || ' ' || r.last_name || ' ' || r.street_address) > .50

)
select * from (
  select distinct on (id) id, first_name, last_name, street_address from matching order by id
 ) d order by street_address;
```

The insert is trivial so I only do select for the insert here.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Comment: This does provide the grouping behavior desired, but now I'm thinking that DUPLICATES perhaps isn't working as I would like. With the above fewer total records are returned. For example, one of the rows for James Faz disappears from the final result. But the same thing happens when I remove DUPLICATES.

Comment: James Faz probably disappears because he has the same ID as Katie Bar (ID=7).  I assumed - maybe incorrectly - it was a mistake.  I added something in the answer that might better suit you.  Not sure how you want this ordered exactly.